PHP/Sql : Problem storing a custom date in the database
I want to manually add a updated/modified date for my WordPress posts. So, when I set a date manually and upload the post, the update date is displayed correctly (and the "_cstm_update_post" field in "wp_postmeta" displays the date correctly too).
But as soon as I click on the "upload" button again to save the article, the date I've modified changes to today's date, and, most curiously, this date disappears from the database (the "_cstm_update_post" field in "wp_postmeta" is empty). Clicking on the save article button without indicating an update date seems to reset the "_cstm_update_post" field in the DB.
Is there an error in my code? I've searched for hours without success.  Thanks.
So, here's the code I'm using in my functions.php child theme :
<?php 
// ADD CUSTOM POST UPDATE DATE/TIME IN ADMIN POST/PAGE META BOX
function add_custom_meta_update() { 
    global $post;
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID , '_cstm_update_post')) {
        $cus_date = date_create(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post')[0]);
        $cus_date_format = date_format($cus_date, 'M d, Y') . " at " . date_format($cus_date, 'H:i');
        $PostDate = 'Updated on: <b>' . $cus_date_format . '</b>'; 
    } else {
        $PostDate = 'No update set';
    }   
    ?>  
    <div class="misc-pub-section post_uptime">
        <span id="updt-datetime"><span class="dashicons dashicons-clock"></span> <?php echo $PostDate ?></span>
        <a href="#edit_timestamp" class="edit-timestamp" role="button"><span class="open-updt-edit">Edit</span></a>
        <div id="updt-timestamp" style="display:none;" ><input type="date" name="_cstm_update_post"></div>
    </div>
    <?php   
}
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'add_custom_meta_update');

// STORE IT IN THE DATABASE
function store_custom_update_time() {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST[ '_cstm_update_post' ])){
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_cstm_update_post']));
    }
} 
add_action('save_post', 'store_custom_update_time');

EDIT : I really wish this code could work, because I've tested using a plugin (WP Last Modified Info) but it doesn't meet all my needs (even though it's an excellent plugin).
WP version: 6.5.4 - Theme : Generatepress free version

if(isset($_POST[ '_cstm_update_post' ])) will be true, even if the field was left empty. In that case, the $_POST entry will only contain an empty string, but it will still be set.

Okay, I used my brain and thanks to the hint left by CBrow (and other posts on StackOverflow), I found the problem (quite tough for my level of PHP/SQL skills ) and modified the code. Here it is, fully functional. The first part displays a form for setting a custom date (timestamp), the second saves this date in the database.
<?php
// ADD CUSTOM POST UPDATE DATE/TIME IN ADMIN POST/PAGE META BOX
function add_custom_meta_update() {
    global $post;
    // RETRIEVE THE CUSTOM UPDATE DATE META VALUE FOR THE CURRENT POST
    $cus_date_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post', true);
    if ($cus_date_meta) {
        $cus_date = date_create($cus_date_meta);
        $cus_date_format = date_format($cus_date, 'M d, Y') . " at " . date_format($cus_date, 'H:i');
        $PostDate = 'Updated on: <b>' . $cus_date_format . '</b>';
    } else {
        $PostDate = 'No update set';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="misc-pub-section post_uptime">
        <span id="updt-datetime"><span class="dashicons dashicons-clock"></span> <?php echo $PostDate; ?></span>
        <a href="#edit_timestamp" class="edit-timestamp" role="button"><span class="open-updt-edit">Edit</span></a>
        <div id="updt-timestamp" style="display:none;">
            <input type="date" name="_cstm_update_post" value="<?php echo esc_attr($cus_date_meta); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'add_custom_meta_update');

// STORE IT IN THE DATABASE
function store_custom_update_time($post_id) {
    // CHECK IF CUSTOM FIELD IS SET
    if (isset($_POST['_cstm_update_post'])) {
        // UPDATE THE POSTMETA WITH THE NEW DATE
        $update_date = sanitize_text_field($_POST['_cstm_update_post']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_cstm_update_post', $update_date);
    } else {
        // IF THE FIELD IS NOT SET, DELETE THE POST META
        delete_post_meta($post_id, '_cstm_update_post');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'store_custom_update_time');
?>

If you want to use it on your WordPress, place it in your child theme's functions.php. Then simply display it somewhere in the article, using a shortcode, for example.
function updated_post_shortcode() {
    global $wp_query, $post, $wpdb;
    $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID; 
    $custom_date = date_create(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cstm_update_post')[0]);
    $PostUpdate = 'Updated on ' . date_format($custom_date, 'F j, Y');
    return $PostUpdate;
}
add_shortcode('updated_post', 'updated_post_shortcode');

